# Laravel Eloquent Search Multiple Related Tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am struggling with figuring out how to run a `like` query against multiple related tables.

I have a `submissions` table that has related `users`, `mcd_forms`, and `submission_statuses` tables.

Here is my code for running a `LIKE` statement with the given `$terms_like`.

```
        $submission = new Submission;

        $terms_like = '%'.$search_terms.'%';

        $data['submissions'] = $submission
            ->join('users as users', 'users.id', '=', 'submissions.user_id')
            ->join('mcd_forms as forms', 'forms.submission_id', '=', 'submissions.id')
            ->join('submission_statuses as statuses', 'statuses.id', '=', 'submissions.submission_status_id')
            ->where(function($q) use ($terms_like) {
                $q->where('users.user_group_id', '=', Auth::user()->user_group_id)
                ->orWhere('forms.name', 'like', $terms_like)
                ->orWhere('forms.custom_id', 'like', $terms_like)
                ->orWhere('forms.start_date', 'like', $terms_like)
                ->orWhere('forms.end_date', 'like', $terms_like)
                ->orWhere('forms.soft_sell_date', 'like', $terms_like)
                ->orWhere('forms.region', 'like', $terms_like)
                ->orWhere('statuses.status_formatted', 'like', $terms_like);
            });
```

No matter what I try it returns incorrect results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your query above, since you are not using the "%" symbol, your like clause is working as an "=" since it's trying to match the whole word.

Replace all the "where" clause like this:

```
->orWhere('forms.name', 'like', "%".$terms_like."%")
```

This will try to match the word anywhere in the text.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am doing that above in my code by I didn't include it in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'like' operator following this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('forms.name','LIKE', '%'.$terms_like.'%')
            ->get();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am doing that above in my code by I didn't include it in my example.

Comment: please be sure about your join query ,if join query works fine then temporarily commit the date fields and run the query